# How to set data (number) format locale for specific cell using Apache POI (SXSSF)?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, locale

The problem is very concrete: using Apache POI, I want to create cell (done), assign number format to it (done), and set format's locale (*stuck here*).

The code looks like this:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(8); //currency with thousands separator and two decimal places after period
cell.setCellValue(123456.78);
//??? how to set custom locale for the cell's number format?
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve with custom locale is customizing thousands separator char (French's non-breaking space is OK for me).

XLSX workbooks allow such customization (update: I mean setting format locale per cell), this is achievable with both MS Office and OpenOffice. I want to do the same in code.

(Apache POI 3.12)

Comment: When I used Apache-poi I didn't have to deal with locale because the localized formatting details (eg. coma or dot) was determined by the Excel which displayed the data so it was always correct for the actual user. Isn't that enough?

Comment: "XLSX workbooks allow such customization": No, it does not. For currency number format only the currency symbol can be localized but not the decimal separator. This comes from Windows system locale settings. And the thousands delimiter also defaults to the Windows system locale settings. But this can be set using a format string. So a format string could be `"#\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C];[RED]\\-#\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C]"`. Is this what you wants? But this is not the same as the localized currency format which is usable in Libreoffice OpenDocument Spreadsheet format.

Comment: @ZsoltV unfortunately this is not enough. I have customer requirement saying "space as delimiter", and I can't get customer to change computers' locale settings

Comment: @AxelRichter XLSX workbook allows to set locale for particular cell. Apache POI doesn't seem to have API for that though. But the trick with format like "# ### ### ###" works for me. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: "XLSX workbook allows to set locale for particular cell." Can you please show how?

Comment: @AxelRichter I meant "Language" combobox on your OpenOffice screenshot

Comment: @Kirill Gamazkov: But the settings of the "Language" combo-box of OpenOffice cannot be stored in `*.xlsx`. Set something else than the default there in OpenOffice, save the file as  `*.xlsx`, close OpenOffice, open the stored  `*.xlsx` file in OpenOffice again. You will see the "Language" is reseted to the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Offixe OpenXML (`*.xlsx`) for currency number format only the currency symbol can be localized but not the decimal separator. The decimal separator comes from Windows system locale settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on. And the thousands delimiter also defaults to the Windows system locale settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on.

In Excel this looks like:

[image]

As you see only the currency symbol can be localized.

At least the thousands delimiter can be set using a format string. So a format string could be

`"#\\ ###\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C];[RED]\\-#\\ ###\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C]"`.

This is currency number format having localized french Euro currency symbol and space as the thousands delimiter. Because we are faking the thousands delimiter, we have to give as much digits as needed in the format string.

The decimal separator is the default, which means it comes from Windows system locale settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on. So the dot `.` within the format string does not means to always use a dot as decimal delimiter but to use the decimal delimiter which comes from the Windows system locale settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on. And if we would had used comma `,` as the thousands delimiter in the format string, this also would had used the thousands delimiter which comes from the Windows system locale settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on. And then we would had not need giving so much digits in the format string because then the thousands delimiter settings would repeat every thousands digits. So

`"#,##0.00\\ [$€-40C];[RED]\\-#,##0.00\\ [$€-40C]"`

would be enough.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;

public class CreateExcelNumberFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);

  DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle cellStyleCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyleCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("#\\ ###\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C];[RED]\\-#\\ ###\\ ##0.00\\ [$€-40C]")); 

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

  cell.setCellValue(123456.78);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyleCurrency);

  ((SXSSFSheet)sheet).trackColumnForAutoSizing(0);
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelNumberFormat.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();
  workbook.dispose();
 }
}
```

But this is not the same as the localized currency format which is usable in Libreoffice OpenDocument Spreadsheet format. This looks like:

[image]

As you see here both, the currency symbol and the language of the whole format, can be localized.

But it is that the Office OpenXML (`*.xlsx`) cannot store localized currency number formats. OpenDocument Spreadsheet (`*.ods`), which is the native format of OpenOffice/Libreoffice, can save localized currency number formats, but if Excel will open such a file, the localization will be lost.

The settings of the "Language" combo-box of OpenOffice/Libreoffice cannot be stored in `*.xlsx`, also not from OpenOffice/Libreoffice. Set something else than the default there in OpenOffice/Libreoffice, save the file as `*.xlsx`, close OpenOffice/Libreoffice, open the stored `*.xlsx` file in OpenOffice/Libreoffice again. You will see the "Language" is reseted to the default.

Comment: I can't quite get what is the difference between format string for Excel and OpenOffice. Is it just spaces being escaped?

Comment: Also I doubt that e. g. 123456789 will be displayed correctly as "123 456 789" - rather as "123456 789". So the complete solution is probably "# ### ### ### ##0" (with many spaces repeated)

Comment: There is not a difference between format string for Excel and OpenOffice/Libreoffice if both are saving Office OpenXML (`*.xlsx`). It is that the Office OpenXML (`*.xlsx`) cannot store localized currency number formats. OpenDocument Spreadsheet (`*.ods`) can save localized currency number formats, but if Excel will open such a file, the localization will be lost. And yes, you are right, because we are faking the thousands delimiter, we have to give as much digits as needed in the format string.